# How to create generic method for ObjectNode put

Tags: java, generics, jackson

I have a use case where I need to support multiple types of values to be inserted into the ObjectNode (of Jackson ObjectMapper), however when I try to use generics it has errors `Cannot resolve method 'put(java.lang.String, T)'`

```java
    public static <T> JsonNode of(String key, T value) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectNode root = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        root.put(key, value); // <== error shows up on this line


        return root;
}
```

The underlying ObjectNode does support many types for the value, e.g. `<String, Boolean>`, `<String, String>`, `<String, Integer>`, etc.

For full documentation [Jackson](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html)

What's the correct way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the signature of the *ObjectNode#put* method you will see that

```
public JsonNode put(String fieldName, JsonNode value)
```

the second argument is actually bound to a specific type and it is `JsonNode` , not just any `T` (much like your method allows).

So, because of the type erasure - the compiler has to ensure you provided a compatible type at compile time and I suggest you to put a suitable bound on the method, for example:

```
public static <T extends JsonNode> JsonNode of(String key, T value) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode root = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
    root.set(key, value);

    return root;
}
```

making sure your method accepts only JsonNode or its descendants.

---

Small note 1: it is not a good thing to instantiate ObjectMapper every time the method gets called as it is a bit expensive object to create, better to make it a field.

Small note 2: The method *ObjectNode#put* gets deprecated since version 2.4, and it is recommended to use *ObjectNode#set* instead.

Comment: After using <T extends JsonNode>, when I invoke the call as JsonNode.of("key", "value") for example, it would complain `no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that String conforms to JsonNode`.

Comment: Of course it complains - now you need your argument to be some instance of `JsonNode`.
The `ObjectNode` has 16+ versions of the `put` method and they could not be generalized unfortunately. Put simply, if such generic method `of(String key, T value)` was allowed and somehow resolved the runtime type of the argument to call an appropriate `ObjectNode#put` version - what would it do if you called you `of` with `null` argument?

What you want is a dynamic method resolution and generics won't help here, you either need to go with lots of overloaded methods OR use reflection/method handles

Comment: You can use `JsonNodeFactory.instance.XXXXX` methods to construct an appropriate `JsonNode` at runtime before you call this `<T extends JsonNode> JsonNode of(String key, T value)`, so that `JsonNode.of("key", "value")` would become `JsonNode.of("key", JsonNodeFactory.instance.textNode("value"))` for example

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that through type erasure, the compiler will produce the method below for your generic method.

```
    public static JsonNode of(String key, Object value) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectNode root = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        root.put(key, value); // <== error shows up on this line
        return root;
}
```

Per Jackson documentation, there's no such method `put(String key, Object value)`.

Instead of calling the method `of(String key, T value)`, I would just do the following:

```
  ObjectNode root = new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode();
  root.put(key, value);
```

Or you could write write several overloaded methods `of(...)`.

Comment: Yes, multiple methods of `of(...)` obviously works. I was just trying to see if there could be simpler way to create these JsonNode using Java's generics support :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach that works for any json object:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>() {});
```

The object in the value can be any value object (`String`, `Integer`, etc), another `Map<String, Object>` as a nested object or a `List<Object>`/`List<Map<String, Object>>` and so on down to any depth.